# Looking for title/author of fantasy trilogy where man is transported via some sort of fairie circle

Tags: story-identification, medieval

Some time in the 90s, I think mid, there was a fantasy trilogy where a man was transported in some sort of fairie circle from the woods near his home to a type of medieval world. I know that the characters that knocked him out used darts to knock him out and those characters were small, more what would be considered "brownies" or such if discussing fairies. He had to do some sort of quests in all three books. I also remember that he aged in the medieval world but not his own, so if he stayed too long, it would be noticeable when he returned home. In I think the 3rd book of the series, he had a fiancee that the brownies also knocked out but weren't going to take but he grabbed one and threatened to crush its head if they didn't but would never do it.

I know this isn't a whole lot of detail, but if anyone has any idea of the series or author, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're thinking of the [Spearwielder's Tale series by R.A. Salvatore](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42273-spearwielder-s-tale).

Wikipedia summary of [the first book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woods_Out_Back), *The Woods Out Back*:

> Gary Leger works at a plastic manufacturing factory. Every day he has the same boring routine. Gary constantly refers to The Hobbit as his favorite book and reads it all the time. In the blueberry patch that is near his house through a steadily receding woodline, he sees a pixie holding a small bow before he passes out on the ground. He then awakes in the mystical forest of Tir'na'nog in the presence of the leprechaun Mickey McMickey. After being seduced by a nymph (Leshiye), he is rescued by the elf Kelsenellenelvial Gil-Ravardy (Kelsey for short), who takes Gary on a quest to re-forge the spear of the legendary hero Cedric Donigarten. There are however two problems. The first is that to re-forge the spear, they require the services of the finest blacksmith alive, the dwarf Geno Hammerthrower. To solve this problem they capture him in his home. The second problem is that it must be forged in the flames of a dragon. On their way to visit the dragon Robert they are captured by the witch Ceridwen. Gary and company, through a plan developed by Gary, escape Ynis Gwydrin with the help of a giant named Tommy and make it to the lair of Robert. Kelsey (or rather an image of Kelsey conjured by Mickey) defeats Robert in single combat and convinces him to reforge the spear. Upon returning home, Gary is assured of the reality of all the events in the book when he sees that his book is still in the script of Mickey McMickey.

In the third book his wife Diane is with him - that may be the "fiancee" part you're remembering.

Comment: Can you expand on what it is about these books that make you think they are a match?

Comment: That is the series I was thinking of. Thank you so much.